# O(1) Amortized + O(k) = O(k) Amortized?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, amortized-analysis

My professor made the following claim:

```
O(1) Amortized + O(k) = O(k) Amortized
```

I agreed with him at first but giving it deep thinking I think it's wrong, why?

`O(1)` Amortized means every `k` operations are done in `O(k)` so `O(1) Amortized = O(k) Worst`.

From here we can conclude: `O(1) Amortized + O(k) = O(1) + O(k) = O(k) Amortized`

Comment: Any help/suggestions?